# Copying windows system32 files to wine system32 folder

Tags: winetricks

I have installed ubuntu 13.10 32-bit with dual boot with windows 7. Can I copy windows 7 system 32 files to wine system32 folder for running my supreme comander,Crysis2 games.

Answer (score 1):

You should install the program on windows then delete everything in the wine c drive and replace it with everything from the windows c drive. I've never done this with windows 7 but I have with windows xp, and I got Call Of Duty 2 running perfectly.

Comment: just make sure this Windows 7 install is 32-bit and not 64-bit